# How to get value from a JSON array column using Redshift?

Tags: json, amazon-redshift

**Background**

I have a table and one of the column contains data that looks like this:

```
[{"category": "Sports & Outdoors", "rank": 218, "link": "www.foop.com"},{"category": "Bike Saddle Covers", "rank": 1, "link" : "www.foo2.com"}]
```

From what I understand, the above is a json array. I tried `select json_array_length(col_1) from mytable` and was able to get back a length of 2 so I know it is a json array.

**Issue**

I am looking to extract value for the key `category` from each json inside the array.
I am unsure how to proceed. I know that if it was a simple json I can do something like  `select col_name -> 'category' from table`.

**What I tried**

```
`select array_to_json(col_1) from mytable`
```

**Error**: `function array_to_json(character varying) does not exist`

I also tried `select array_to_json(col_1::varchar) from mytable`

I would appreciate any help here as i am very new to sql and have only done basic querying.

Comment: @Serge thank you. I tired your suggestion but i got the following error: 

Syntax Error: Database: prod-redshift (Amazon Redshift)
at or near "select"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite Redshift is based on Postgres it's [different in some parts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html).

[JSON functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html) are very limited in redshift. The only possible solution for your task with these functions which I can imagine is:

```sql
select
    json_extract_path_text(
        json_extract_array_element_text(col_1, 0),
        'category')
from mutable
union
select
    json_extract_path_text(
        json_extract_array_element_text(col_1, 1),
        'category')
from mutable;
```

which results in

[image]

That for sure is not very scalable solution if you have a complex JSON structure or many elements inside a JSON array.

using `null_if_invalid` param can help for some extent

```sql
select
    json_extract_path_text(
        json_extract_array_element_text(col_1, 0),
        'category'
    )
from mutable

union
select
    json_extract_path_text(
        json_extract_array_element_text(col_1, 1, true),
        'category', true)
from mutable

union
select
    json_extract_path_text(
        json_extract_array_element_text(col_1, 2, true),
        'category', true)
from mutable

union
select
    json_extract_path_text(
        json_extract_array_element_text(col_1, 3, true),
        'category', true)
from mutable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You build a join of the table and json array

```
SELECT arr.item ->> 'category'
FROM myTable, json_array_elements(col1) arr(item)
```

Here `arr(item)` is arbitrary notation that allow us to reference individual elements of the json array. Here is tutorial for that case

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/working-with-a-jsonb-array-of-objects-in-postgresql-d2b7e7f4db87